# Back button controlling for my Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight App

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, back-button

I am developing a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app. In my app, I need to override the back button code.

So I tried this,

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        //Navigating to this page when back button is pressed
        DisplayPage mynewPage = new DisplayPage();
        this.Content = mynewPage;

        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

But this code is not working. What am I doing wrong? Please help me out.

EDIT:

When I place this code on MainPage, it works! But I don't want to place it there. I want to place it on other pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove "e.Cancel = true" (it cancels the navigation). Simply just navigate to the new page.

EDIT:

For navigating to another page, I would rather suggest using NavigationService. Check out [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff626521(v=vs.105).aspx) for examples.

EDIT:

Code snippet:

```
    protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        //Navigating to this page when back button is pressed
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/DisplayPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

    }
```

Comment: @ShahriarSirajSnigdho

Did you try it like this? 

protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e) { NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/DisplayPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative)); } 

This always worked for me.

Comment: No! Not working! Whenever I'm pressing the back button, the app is closing. I think the method of overriding back button is somehow not correct

Comment: When I place this code on MainPage, it works! But I don't want to place it there. I want to place it on other pages.

Comment: That's weird, should be doing the same on other pages too. How do your pages look like?